# How can I make an Ubuntu recovery image on external media?

Tags: live-usb, backup, data-recovery, disk-image

I am about to expand my Ubuntu partition, so I think I should make a backup of the current one in case something goes wrong.

Is there some software to make a bootable USB and recovery image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Remastersys](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/create-full-system-backup-or-custom.html) is the tool to go for. It allows you to make an ISO image of your system including if you want your data. You can than create a bootable USB stick. My last experience was that the live usb/cd didnt work, but installation worked. In conclusion a perfect toll for your needs and or if you want to transfer a system to a friends computer.

Comment: what do you mean, "My last experience was that the live usb/cd didnt work, but installation worked"? Remastersys didn't work? Or it did work?

Comment: It did work, but, when you get the menu and choosed live session it didnt work, but if zou choosed instal it installed.

Answer (score 4):

This is rather basic, but it's guaranteed to work, provided you have an external hard drive with enough free space to hod your entire internal drive (including free space)

### To Backup

1. Boot into a live CD/USB environment.
2. Determine the name of your internal hard drive. Probably, it's `/dev/sda`, but you should check somewhere to be absolutely sure. I use GParted for this purpose.
3. Mount your external drive somewhere. I'll use `/media/external` in these instructions. **Be sure that your internal drive is *not* mounted!**
4. Choose one of the following, depending on your situation. Both make use of `dd` to image your entire disk, not just individual partitions (you can also use this technique to migrate to an entirely different hard drive of the same size or larger):

   1. If your external drive's filesystem can handle a single file the size of your entire internal drive, you can use the simplest option:

      ```
      sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/external/internal_disk.img
      ```
   2. If you need compression or need to split the image file into multiple smaller files, use this more complex command (see the `man` pages for any commands you don't understand):

      ```
      cd /media/external
      sudo dd if=/dev/sda | bzip2 | split --bytes=2G -d - internal_disk.img.
      ```

      This will first compress the contents of your disk (`bzip2`), then split it into 2GB chunks.
5. Your backup is complete.

### To Restore

1. Boot into a live CD/USB environment.
2. Mount your external drive. I'll make the same path assumptions as I did above.
3. Choose the option that corresponds to the choice you made above:

   1. Just copy the image to your hard drive:

      ```
      sudo dd if=/media/external/internal_disk.img of=/dev/sda
      ```
   2. Make sure that there are no other files in your backup directory that have names beginning the same as your backup chunks. Then:

      ```
      cd /media/external
      cat internal_disk.img.* | bunzip2 | sudo dd of=/dev/sda
      ```
4. Reboot. You're finished.

Comment: how do you get the required ubuntu live  usb?

Comment: Download Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small research;
The only Backup tool with ext4 support seems to be "**FSArchiver**".

See more at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/How_To_Backup_Operating_Systems#Create_Partition_Backup_-_FSArchiver_Method